# How to fix Object is possibly 'null' in input?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make authentication on my app, but I'm stuck with this error:

`Object is possibly 'null'.`

I tried using `emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)`, 'if loop' and `createElement('input')` , but nothing really works for me, maybe i just do something wrong. Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Here's my code below:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './auth.scss';
import { Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const validateMessages = {
  required: '${label} is required',
  types: {
    email: '${label} is not a valid email!',
    password: '${label} is not a valid password',
  },
};

const Auth = (props: { onLogin: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> }) => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const emailInputRef = useRef(null);
  const passwordInputRef = useRef(null);

  const switchAutModeHandler = () => {
    setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const onFinish = () => {
    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
    if (isLogin) {
    } else {
      fetch(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyBlA5nVIWyzfqUKZhv8EqOiIqaMhHgqOJg',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: enteredEmail,
            password: enteredPassword,
            returnSecureToken: true,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>{isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign up'}</h1>
      <Form
        className="auth__form"
        name="auth"
        onFinish={onFinish}
        validateMessages={validateMessages}
        initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      >
        <Form.Item
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          rules={[{ required: true, type: 'email' }]}
        >
          <Input ref={emailInputRef} />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          rules={[{ required: true, min: 6, max: 12 }]}
        >
          <Input ref={passwordInputRef} />
        </Form.Item>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          htmlType="submit"
          className="form__button"
          onClick={props.onLogin}
        >
          {isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register'}
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={switchAutModeHandler}
          type="text"
          className="form--button"
        >
          {isLogin ? 'Create new account' : 'Login with existing account'}
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Comment: which object is possibly null? can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: @IgorGonak 

    TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
    23 |
    24 |   const onFinish = () => {
  > 25 |     const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
       |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    26 |     const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

Comment: your refs are null for some reason. What version of antd are you using? Do you need to work with ref? Cant' you solve it with useState?

Comment: This is my version: "antd": "^4.20.1".
I could use useState, but as a begginer I prefer to solve the problem than omit it.

Comment: It's just I'm not familiar with antd... Try to check why are ref.current values are null.

Comment: Well, now. The error disappeared after I changed ```const enteredEmail = emailInputRef. current. value;``` to ```const enteredEmail = emailInputRef. current```